# Jenkins fails to create new Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file

Tags: android, jenkins

[Settings for Android Emulator when it fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhndp.png)

```
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
[android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_120_WVGA_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_23_google_apis-armeabi-v7a.avd
[android] /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -f -a -s WVGA800 -n hudson_en-US_120_WVGA_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_23_google_apis-armeabi-v7a -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a
[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file
```

But as soon as I am entering Android OS Version to: 6.0 . It will succeed to create new emulator and it runs.

My requirement is that is need Google Maps support for emulator.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem and the answers below didn't work for me?

Answer (score 2):

Install required libraries for 64-bit machines:

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
 sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0
```

If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

source : https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Comment: For whom it may interest. For this commands to work you might need to do `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and `sudo apt-get update` before. Also `libbz2-1.0:i386` instead of `lib32bz2-1.0`. Still, this solution didn't work for me. Anyone has more ideas?

Comment: @user2299735 it's not working for me on my Jenkins server having Ubuntu on aws ec2 instance  $ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc6
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5
E: Unable to locate package libstdc++6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++6'

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, and it was a matter of permissions. I installed all the android sdk dependencies from a ssh console with user "console_user", and then Jenkins was triying to run the tools with user "jenkins". The solution comes in various steps:

1. Add user "jenkins" to group "console_user".
2. Add group write permissions to the android sdk home dir and all the subdirectories:

   `chmod g+w $ANDROID_HOME -R`.

Hope this helps or at least give you an advice.

Comment: what OS is this ran under? "console_user" is not a group that I have. If you mean the group associated with my user who own the sdk tools I have tried that it did not work.

Comment: This was Ubuntu 16.04 (or 15.10, don't remember). "console_user" is your user in the console, and the group associated with that user. You should make sure that jenkins user can write in the android sdk folder and all the subfolders (maybe not all the subfolders, but just in case).

Comment: with the android plugin jenkins has all the tools it needs in `/var/lib/jenkins/tools` that is already under the jenkins user and group. Am I assuming your advice is not for the Android plugin but if you want to do the commands by manually without the plugin.

Comment: I did that way because I installed the android sdk manually by console.

Comment: awww i see, yeah I might abandon the plugin and go this route then

Comment: Besides, only after installing the correct AVD image and SDK from command-line I became able to create the emulator successfully.

Follow below the steps: 
android list sdk --all -e | grep "android-22" 
android list sdk --all -e | grep "sys-img-x86-android-22"

Grab the id's and then run:

android update sdk -u -a -t  {android-22-id, sys-img-22}

Comment: How could I add jenkins to the group 'console_user' if my `$ANDROID_HOME` is in a slave machine and my jenkins user is in the master instance? I tried just giving the write permissions since I ssh from the master with `console_user` anyway. But still not working.